# How to create QR bar automatically for my module?

Tags: python, qr-code

I am trying to create user module with QR id generation. I have created my module. I want add QR code generation in my module automatically. Tell me, what do I do?

python method(part of the python coding):

```
 def barcode(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
   qr = QRCode(version=20, error_correction=ERROR_CORRECT_L)
   qr.add_data("http://sample:/")
   qr.make()
   im = qr.make_image()
   im.save("sample.png")
```

while i am running my application the following error is shown.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 29, in save
    self._img.save(stream, kind)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1433, in save
    fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'sample.png'
```

how to clear permission error

Comment: You need to specify a lot more details, like what languages are working with, what are your input, do you want to save to QR code as an image, etc.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning. I have created own module in openerp using xml and python.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that your code tries to save the file in a directory does not have write permission. Try not saving it under the usr directory or run it with `sudo` to give it permission.

Comment: i tried. but that error changed like this NO Such directory

Comment: Are you sure the directory exists, that you have spelled it right, and the name does not have any spaces?

Comment: thanks for answer. i have found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am giving file permission to openerp user. It is 
corrected